# Implementing MOSFET Driver & Simplifying MOSFET Switching Design

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, power-electronics, mosfet-driver

I am leaning a lot from the great community here, and I think I have a solution to my project of a high power Battery MOSFET switch. My previous questions was getting quite long, and I now have a different question related to the same project. You can see the discussion here - [Pre-charge Anti Spark MOSFET Switch for Li-ion Battery](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/608371/pre-charge-anti-spark-mosfet-switch-for-li-ion-battery)

So I have drawn out the circuit based on the great advise of @jimBeaux27
& @tihjs however after reading datasheets of MOSFET Drivers I am a little lost how to use them effectively. I also think this circuit can be simplified a lot, I just cant see how best to achieve that.

I have found these examples also - [Using a momentary push button as a latching on-off toggle switch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/using-a-momentary-push-button-as-a-latching-on-off-toggle-switch)

[image]

I have attached my proposed circuit below. Many thanks, Jack

[image]

Comment: Q6 circuit does nothing and does not make sense. R3 is required otherwise the gates may float.

Comment: The voltage divider formed by R1/R3 means Q1-Q5's Vgs will only reach 1.68V, which may not be sufficient depending on the MOSFET. R1 being 1M also limits the switch-on gate current to 68uA shared between all MOSFETs, so if they all turn on at the same time that's only 13.6uA each. Those transistors are going to turn on very slowly, if at all, so if you're planning to shunt much current through them they're going to get hot. Napkin maths puts the turn-on time for 13.6uA into a 50nC gate charge at more than 3.5 milliseconds. I'd consider using gate driver ICs here.