# Build an H-Bridge Motor Driver with 4 N-Channel MOSFET

Tags: motor, mosfet, pwm, driver, h-bridge

I have bought 4 N-Channel MOSFETs to build an H-Bridge Motor Driver.
My Motor drive and my power supply voltage is 12v.
My TTL logic voltage is 5v as I want to speed up/down the motor with uC PWM.
Now I have understood that I have problem with driving High Side MOSFETs as their Gate Voltage must be bigger in respect to their Source voltage.
What are my options now? shall I change them to P-Channel MOSFETs?

Comment: It would certainly simplify your circuit if you used P MOSFETs - you only need to replace two of them.

Comment: @JImDearden Will I be limited to a lower current if I use P MOSFET? as I need 5A current for my Motor

Comment: no - just make sure you get one that is complimentary to the N type. It will switch as much current.

Comment: How can I figure it out that it is complimentary to mine or not? Mine are P5N60

Comment: look up the data sheet - the P5N60 is a 5A, 600V N MOSFET so your looking for a P MOSFET 5A, -600V. You may also want to match the DRAIN-SOURCE resistance. As you don't need 600V you could safely choose a lower voltage type - say 30V.

Comment: What will be the concerns if they won't be exactly the same? Cause I found a 5.6A 200V P MOSFET. What will happen if I have slightly current different and voltage difference? my motor will not working or I would have another issue?

Answer (score 3):

Check out this device.

http://www.linear.com/product/LT1910

It's a high side N-channel MOSFET driver. I think that it has a little boost converter internally. We've just started playing with these and it will drive the MOSFET gate to 20 VDC with a 12 VDC supply. Nifty huh?!?

Though the device isn't fast, relatively speaking, so you would be better off doing PWM for speed control on the low side MOSFET. You can get a regular FET driver to do this with your 5 V input.

Answer (score 1):

For half bridge just use one of these: -

[image]

For full bridge use two. These devices are able to drive n channels topside because they smuggle a bit of energy away from the output using a capacitor \$C_{BOOST}\$. The 1N4148 is for startup I believe.

There are other devices that can do this too.

Comment: Use of 1N4148 explained here : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79257/need-help-choosing-h-bridge-driver?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely possible but you need some way to generate the higher-than-supply gate voltage required by the high-side MOSFET. There are several possible ways of doing this:

1. Generate this high side voltage from a separate source, using something like a sub-US$0.1 chip like `MC34063` connected into a small boost converter. This method works with any drive waveform
2. Use a gate driver chip like the sub-$1 `IR2110`. This requires a PWM drive waveform as it generates this high voltage using a bootstrap process (essentially a switched capacitor synchronous charge pump)

Answer (score 0):

You should Use IR2101, Its a half bridge gate driver IC with all the details mentioned inits datasheet. Its very useful.try it.